# File permissions on NFS mount show up as 'nobody' after upgrading to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, nfs

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server that exports a couple of filesystems over NFS.

```
server$ cat /etc/exports
/home 192.168.42.0/255.255.255.0(rw,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,async,no_subtree_check)
/stuff 192.168.42.0/255.255.255.0(rw,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,async,no_subtree_check)
/stuff 192.168.99.0/255.255.255.0(ro,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,async,no_subtree_check)
```

I also have a client that mounts them:

```
client$ cat /etc/fstab
...
server:/home    /home       nfs hard,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,_netdev 0 0
server:/stuff   /server/stuff   nfs hard,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,_netdev 0 0
```

The client's IP is in the 192.168.42.x range.  It was running Ubuntu 10.04 until yesterday.  NFS worked fine, more or less (sometimes it wouldn't automount on boot, but I had a cron script to detect and fix that).

I upgraded the client to Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday and rebooted.  NFS continued to work fine.

I upgraded the client to Ubuntu 14.04 today and rebooted.  Now NFS is mounted but all file ownership information is mapped to nobody:4294967294:

```
client$ ls -ld /home/weblate
drwxr-xr-x   5 nobody 4294967294     4096 Jan 29  2014 weblate
```

Why is that and what do I need to do to make file ownership work again?

Comment: I'm reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto now, especially the bits about NFSv4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The vital clue showed up in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Sep 16 13:11:07 client nfsidmap[7340]: nss_getpwnam: name 'www-data@lan' does not map into domain 'localdomain'
```

combined with this excerpt from [NFSv4Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto)

> If all directory listings show just "nobody" and "nogroup" instead of real user and group names, then you might want to check the Domain parameter set in /etc/idmapd.conf. NFSv4 client and server should be in the same domain.

and this comment in `/etc/idmap.conf`:

```
# set your own domain here, if id differs from FQDN minus hostname
# Domain = localdomain
```

So turns out my server thought its domain was `lan`:

```
server$ hostname -f
server.lan

server$ grep server /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1   server.lan server
```

while my client didn't have a domain:

```
client$ hostname -f
client

client$ grep client /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1   client
```

**The fix:** edit `/etc/hosts` on the client to read

```
127.0.1.1   client.lan client
```

and reboot.

Comment: `/var/log/syslog` on the client or the server?

Comment: @7yl4r: on the client.

Comment: I'd like to add that in `/etc/hosts` the order is important, that is, the FQDN needs to come first. So **do not** write `127.0.1.1  client  client.lan`, but `127.0.1.1  client.lan  client`.

Comment: also, consider adding `nfsidmap -c`; apparently, it clears some caches that stay around even after restarting nfs.idmapd.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by this method. Open the file `/etc/nfsmount.conf` and find `Nfsvers=`.

Uncomment that line and write the NFS version which is supported by your server. Mine was 3 so I wrote:

```
Nfsvers=3
```

The I restarted the NFS server.

Comment: But aren't you missing out on functionality by not using NFSv4?